# Is there a way in Angular2 to display all validations once the entire form is traversed?

Tags: forms, angular

I am using Angular2 (2.2.1) for building my web app. I am facing a challenge here. I have multiple dynamic forms in my SPA and in all of them, I am keeping my Sumbit button disabled till all the mandatory fields are filled (I cannot change this behavior because of some restrictions).

My errors are displayed once the field is dirty (and of course if there are errors). However I would like to show that the user has missed some field completely once he has reached the end of the form. I thought of keeping the check on the last field of the form, ie. once it's touched, the validations for all the missing fields will be shown. However there is a major flaw in my logic here as it assumes no user will ever miss the last field which may not be the case.

So, is there any way this can be done in Angular2?

Comment: Add a condition to your error displaying until all the field (declared in an array?) are not pristine anymore?

Comment: That will work only when the field has been touched and not otherwise